# Entity Framework. Проблема добавления записей с Foreign Key

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Есть очень простой сценарий работы с Entity Framework. Я использую подход Code First и у меня есть два класса:

```
public class First
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}    

public class Second
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual First Foreign { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date {get; set; }        
}
```

и контекст:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("MyConnection")
    { }

    public DbSet<First> FirstTable { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Second> SecondTable { get; set; }
}
```

затем я создаю список сущностей Second и пытаюсь добавить их в базу. При этом разные Second из этого массива могут иметь одинаковые поля First (обычное отношение 1 ко многим).

```
var f = new First {Id = 1, Name = "first"};
var s = new First { Id = 2, Name = "second" };

res = new List<Second>();
res.Add(new Second { Date = DateTime.Now, Foreign = f });
res.Add(new Second { Date = DateTime.Now, Foreign = s });
res.Add(new Second { Date = DateTime.Now, Foreign = f });

using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var firsts = new[] {f, s};
    foreach (var item in firsts)
        ctx.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;

    foreach (var item in res) 
    {
        ctx.FirstTable.Attach(item.Foreign);         
        ctx.SecondTable.Add(item);
    } 
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Казалось бы все очень просто: есть таблица FirstTable связанная с таблицей SecondTable отношением один ко многим через foreign key в таблице SrcondsTable.

Но тут я получаю исключение

`The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Seconds_dbo.Firsts_Foreign_Id". The conflict occurred in database "MyDatabase", table "dbo.Firsts", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.`

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Попробуйте еще раз

Comment: @PavelMayorov пробовал и не раз

Comment: `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` означает, что вы сами должны задавать значение ключа. Очевидно, у вас они дублируются.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov они вообще не должны добавляться в таблицу, если сделать `ctx.FirstTable.Attach(item.Foreign);`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, ключи дублируются и их значения задаются мной. Мне как раз и нужен способ, который позволит вставлять данные в таблицу SecondTable без исключений при дублировании. Пробовал `ctx.FirstTable.Attach(item.Foreign); ` но это не помогает

Comment: @Pupkin первичный ключ не может дублироваться. Никак не может.

Comment: @PavelMayorov разумеется я это понимаю. Просто мне нужно как-то объяснить Entity Framework'у, что если item.Foreign уже есть в таблице FirstTable, то добавлять его не нужно, а нужно добавить только item в таблицу SecondTable и в качестве FirstTable_Id записать идентификатор существующей записи

Comment: @Pupkin EF так не работает.

Comment: @PavelMayorov хорошо, а как тогда решить эту задачу?

Comment: @Pupkin используйте Attach и не делайте дублей -- К.О.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я изменил вопрос и привел код к самому простому виду, где я использую Attach. Посмотрите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Вроде бы тривиальный случай связи 1 ко многим, но почему-то возникают порблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код переусложнен. Уберите строчки

```
foreach (var item in firsts)
    ctx.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
```

и

```
    ctx.FirstTable.Attach(item.Foreign);
```

-- тогда все заработает.

Comment: я и правда переусложнил. Спасибо, работает